# Angular-ui Google map center error

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use angular-ui google map and npm installed all the necessary dependencies needed however when I load the page up its giving me. Tried to re-install everything and no avail.

> angular-google-maps: could not find a valid center property

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
$scope.map = {
            center: {
                lat: 51.5072,
                lng: -0.1275
            },
            zoom: 8,
            minZoom: 2,
            maxZoom: 15
        };
```

Can anyone shed a light on this one please.

Answer (score 0):

In the center object you need to name the points latitude and longitude rather then lat and lng.

```
$scope.map = {
          center: {
                 latitude: 51.5072, 
                 longitude: -0.1275
          },
          zoom: 8,
          minZoom: 2,
          maxZoom: 15 
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KGmlQVV1mFu2IwIJm8AV?p=preview